# Is it possible to set color/format for error output in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

By default error output in Node is a giant grey wall.

For expample

```
ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at exports.register (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/user/controller.js:2:31)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
```

1. Is it possible to set different color for error type, place and position?
   Approach might be similar to color output in console, where one does something like

```sh
PS1="\[${folderStyle}\W\]" # working directory base name
PS1+="${reset}"
PS1+="\n"; # newline
PS1+="\[${userStyle}\]\u"; # username
PS1+="\[${light_blue}\] at ";
PS1+="\[${hostStyle}\]\h"; # host
PS1+="${reset}"
PS1+="\[${light_blue}\] in";
PS1+=" ${c}\w";            #working directory
PS1+="\$(prompt_git \"\[${light_blue}\] on \[${c}\](\[${green}\]\" \"\[${green}\]\")\[${c}\])"; # git repository details
PS1+="\n";
PS1+="${reset}"
```

2. Other solution may be a code parser for terminal (or hyper), so it will treat output as shell-script.

For example, here is an output treated as shell-script:

```sh
ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at exports.register (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/user/controller.js:2:31)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/boleeluchshiy/Documents/Ryukzak/node/ryu-node/_workbook/passport auth2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

...
```

Comment: How about https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors and set a condition for each possible error?

Comment: So, yes, question is how to format node output :) (edited my question and added possible solving paths)